# getting all radio button input values and storing them as json in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

how do i get all **values of a radio button** and store them in as json with input name as key and the input value as the value. I am having problem trying to get all the values of the radio button input.Am able to get the value of a single radio button though.

Comment: a radio button has a single value, probably you mean all values of a group of radio buttons, right? But what do you want to use this json for then? How do you want to use this with vue.js?

Comment: probably you'd like save the json object or string into localStorage/sessionStorage. I don't think the security policy allow your script to save one file into local.

Comment: In Vue, you should already have those values. That's how they get into the radio buttons to begin with. You might need to explain your problem in more detail and show some code.

Comment: @MarcoPantaleoni, yes want it for a group of radio buttons